# How to convert a type in C# from a string to a JObject

Tags: c#, json.net

since I am at the end of my C# knowledge, I would like to ask if anyone can help me with the conversion problem.

My error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot
>   implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'string'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Where it gets triggered:

```
JObject obj = NAPI.Data.GetEntitySharedData(veh.Handle, "VehicleSyncData");
return obj.ToObject<VehicleSyncData>();
```

Based on RageMP (a mulitplayer modification for GTA V) and NAPI is basically an API from them to get data.

Comment: Write it this way `dynamic obj = NAPI.Data.GetEntitySharedData(veh.Handle, "VehicleSyncData");` and see types at runtime (DEBUG your code). Since it returns dynamic nobody knows what type it is.